# Nodejs loop through array / object

Tags: arrays, node.js, object

I have an array with object inside, it looks like:

```
{
"result":{
"items":[
{
"id":1,
"name":"item_name_1",
},
{
"id":2,
"name":"item_name_2",
},
{
"id":3,
"name":"item_name_3",
}
]
,
"status":200
}
}
```

What I need, is the way how to go through this stuff and get ID and Name for each item. I tried to for, but all I got is a lot of numbers or nothing.

And an other question, can you please explain what is the difference between array and object in JS. (only if you can/want).

Thank you!

Comment: Responding your second question, an array is a collection of elements (any kind of elements, like objects in this case). For example:
`[1, 2, 3, 4]`
`["Facebook", "Twitter", "Tumblr"]`
`[{"id":2, "name": item2}, {"id":3, "name": item3}]`

What you are using are JSON objects, they help describing 'something' take a look at [http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
yourObj.result.items.forEach((item)=>{  
    // do something with each item   
    console.log(item);
})
```

replace @yourObj with your variable that holds the object you indicated in your question

**EDIT** In JavaScript an Array is an object, even functions are objects. You can easily find these explanations in other questions